# Property getter simplification via delegation

Tags: kotlin

I have many properties that follow this pattern, basically the only things that change from the template below are:

1. the initialized value
2. the property name

### code

```
var foo: Double = 0.0
    get() { 
        update()
        return field
    }

var foo2: Double = 1.23
    get() { 
        update()
        return field
    }
```

### question

is there any way that I can use delegation to to simplify (reduce the verbosity of) the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure

```
private fun <T> publishingDelegate(value: T): ReadWriteProperty<Any?, T> = object: ReadWriteProperty<Any?, T> {
    private var initValue = value

    override fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        update()
        return initValue
    }

    override fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        update()
        initValue = value
    }
}

var foo: Double by publishingDelegate(0.0)
var foo2: Double by publishingDelegate(1.23)
```

Comment: @ycomp oh, ok. I've updated my answer for mutable property